# displaying data from a users table and a leads table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `users` table with `id` as the Primary Key and a `leads` table with `id` as the Foreign Key. I want to display the information from the users table by the `users`'s `id` along with the `id` from the `leads` table:

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()) {

    $this->_error = false;

    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

public function get($table, $where) {
    return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking questions, please provide a specific example of what you're trying to achieve and also what you've currently done. In its current state, your question can't really be answered and may be closed. To learn more about asking great questions, see How to Ask- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. You can also take a look at the About page and if you ever need to check over something, the Help center- http://stackoverflow.com/help is a good resource. Thank you!

Comment: public function query($sql, $params = array()) {

  $this->_error = false;

  if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
   $x = 1;
   if(count($params)) {
    foreach($params as $param) {
     $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
     $x++;
    }
   }

   if($this->_query->execute()) {
    $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
   } else {
    $this->_error = true;
   }
  }
  
  return $this;
 }

 public function get($table, $where) {
  return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
 }

Comment: It would be helpful for you: http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/optimizing-sql-queries-with-joins/

Answer (score 1):

Have you coded it yet or not?. You need to use Joins.

```
Select u.id , l.id from users u, leads l where u.id = l.user_id
```

or

all data frm users and only id frm leads

```
Select u.* , l.id from users u, leads l where u.id = l.user_id
```

assuming user_id is the column name in leads table

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.*, l.id
FROM users u
JOIN leads l ON u.id = l.id
```

This might be a start for you

Comment: Select u.id , l.* from users u, leads l where u.id = l.user_id

Comment: This seem to work:-    Select u.id , l.* from users u, leads l where u.id = l.user_id     But i need it to only show a users id that is logged in or user id.  The above show all records

Comment: You didn't mention that in the question, you just wrote "I want to show the information from the users table". So yes if you have an id specifically then simply add a WHERE u.id = $loggedInID